# Django - http code 304, how to workaround in the testserver?

Tags: django, django-templates, http-status-code-304

I have a CSS code that generates http 304:

```
[08/Nov/2011 15:22:07] "GET /site_media/logo1.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

How can I get a workaround using the Django test server? Any clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: Seems to be duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730274/how-to-prevent-http-304-in-django-test-server

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `304` code is not an error. You don't need a workaround. It simply means that the static file has not changed since your browser last accessed it

For more information see the [Wikipedia explanation of 3xx status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).

Answer (score 7):

If you're getting 304 with files you did change, you can force reloading in your browser by checking "Disable cache" in your browser's dev tools (on Chrome/ium, right click on webpage -> inspect element -> go to network tab -> disable cache)

Comment: thanks for that answer, was struggling for couple of hours to get css/js reloaded)

Comment: is there anyway that we apply these force with coding, i try some way like adding no-cache header or using no-cache decorator but this way has not any impact on js or css files ...

Comment: @LordST do you need it for production? That's not such a good idea because it would make your web app slower. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6460967/2430274

Comment: @emisilva I found storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage class in django itself, I think that's what i want, i working on it right now ...