# Django css not rendering from amazon server- 304 not modified

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am using a amazon server to host my Django app. It used to work fine but after some changes in the css files the app is not rendering those files anymore. I ran python manage.py collectstatic. Through firebug I can see the css files through up the error 304 not modified.
I guess this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730274/how-to-prevent-http-304-in-django-test-server) address the issue but I couldnt understand it! What should I do to make so that static files render properly?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use something like `/path/to/style.css?ver=CURRENT_VERSION` to ensure that all users get recent version of CSS, JS and other static. `CURRENT_VERSION` could even be auto-populated from current Git commit id on deploy.

Comment: where should I add this code-/path/to/style.css?ver=CURRENT_VERSION ?

Comment: Where you are using these static files, usually in LINK tag in your templates.